# How to determine if data is increasing or decreasing in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, math, statistics, linear-regression

Let's say we have the following data in an array:

`$data1 = [3,5,7,6,8,9,13,14,17,15,16,16,16,18,22,20,21,20];`

`$data2 = [23,18,17,17,16,15,16,14,15,10,11,7,4,5];`

As with `$data1` we can say the data is increasing while in `$data2` it is decreasing.

Using PHP, how do you know the data is increasing or decreasing, and is there a way on how to measure
know the rate of increasing as well as decreasing i.e in terms of percentage.

**Edit**

From the comments I received I got an idea and here is what I have tried.
What I want to achieve;

1. I want to know if the trend of the data coming in is upwards or downwards.
2. Want also to know the rate at which the data is rising or droping. For example `$data1 = [1,3,5];` is not the same as `$data2 = [1, 20, 55];`. You can see `$data1` rate of increase is not the same as `$data2`.

```php
function increaseOrDecrease($streams = []) : array
{
        $streams = [3,5,7,6,8,9,13,14,17,15,16,16,16,18,22,20,21,20]; // For the increasing

        //$streams = [23,18,17,17,16,15,16,14,15,10,11,7,4,5]; // For the decreasing

        $first = 0;
        $diff = [];

        foreach ($streams as $key => $number) {
            if ($key != 0) {
                $diff[] = $number - $first;
            }
            $first = $number;
        }        

        $avgdifference = array_sum($diff)/count($diff); //Get the average

        $side = $avgdifference > 0 ? 'UP' : 'DOWN';

        $avgsum = array_sum($streams)/count($streams);

        $percentage = abs($avgdifference)/$avgsum * 100;
        
        if ($side == 'UP') {            
            $data = [
                'up' => true,
                'percent' => $percentage,
            ];            
        }else {
            $data = [
                'up' => false,
                'percent' => $percentage,
            ];
        }

        return $data;
}
```

I would like some help to refactor this code or the best approach to solve the issue.

Comment: _terms of percentage_ , percentage of what ?

Comment: Its all about data structures. Nothing more, nothing less. What about a min and a max heap, that stores values with all the functionalities of a heap?

Comment: I would have expected more from someone who's profile states 'PHP Developer with +10 years Experience'

Comment: may be ``if($data[0] > end($data)) // decreasing`` and vice-versa if that's what you mean by your question

Comment: If I have like `$data = [4,10];`, I would say the data is increasing since I have only 2 values. The problem is I have more than 2 values in an array.

Comment: @muya.dev just take the first element and last element and compare the both. You can find if it's increasing or decreasing !! What's so tough about it?

Comment: What should be the desired output of `$data = [3,2,1,4];` ?

Comment: There's a couple of ways that I think you can bucket this. 1) Always increasing, where `n+1` is always greater than `n`. 2) Always decreasing, where `n+1` is always less than `n`. 3) Never changing, where `n+1` is the same as `n`. Anything that doesn't fit those patterns would be "other". The `n+1` should be pretty easy to do in a loop.

Comment: @OMiShah - The operative phrase is "rate of increase / decrease"

Comment: @NigelRen I have added more details editing my question, Please let me know if it is clear, Thank you

Comment: `$data1` is not *monotonically* increasing nor is `$data2` *monotonically decreasing. Regarding `$data1`, the last element, 20, is greater than the first element, 3. So you can say that the *overall trend* is towards increasing numbers. An analogy: You start at elevation 100 feet and via a walk that takes you up and down hills you finally end up at an elevation of 109 feet. The amount of work you have done against gravity is the change in potential energy, which would be your weight  * change in height (9 feet). How you got there is irrelevant. (more...)

Comment: If the difference between successive elements is not constant, then what you call rate is not a constant. Think of your list elements as being values plotted on a Y axis with X= 0 for the first element, X = 1 for the second element, etc. Then the difference between successive values is the slope or rate of change. But we arbitrarily chose the X values as 0, 1, 2, etc. We could have just as easily chose 0, 2, 4, etc., which would have resulted in a different rate of change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to analyze data and extract a trend. The most classical method is called
[least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares). It's a way of fitting a line
through the data. The method computes the slope and the intercept of the line. The trend is just the slope.

The formulas are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_linear_regression_model).

A PHP implementation is the following:

```php
function linearRegression($x, $y)
{
    $x_sum = array_sum($x);
    $y_sum = array_sum($y);
    $xy_sum = 0;
    $x2_sum = 0;
    $n = count($x);
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
    {
        $xy_sum += $x[$i] * $y[$i];
        $x2_sum += $x[$i] * $x[$i];
    }
    $beta = ($n * $xy_sum - $x_sum * $y_sum) / ($n * $x2_sum - $x_sum * $x_sum);
    $alpha = $y_sum / $n - $beta * $x_sum / $n;
    return ['alpha' => $alpha, 'beta' => $beta];
}

function getTrend($data)
{
    $x = range(1, count($data)); // [1, 2, 3, ...]
    $fit = linearRegression($x, $data);
    return $fit['beta']; // slope of fitted line
}
```

Examples:

```php
echo getTrend([1, 2, 3]); // 1
echo getTrend([1, 0, -1]); // -1
echo getTrend([3,5,7,6,8,9,13,14,17,15,16,16,16,18,22,20,21,20]); // 1.065
echo getTrend([23,18,17,17,16,15,16,14,15,10,11,7,4,5]); // -1.213
```

Answer (score 4):

You are asking for a type of data structure that can represent ascending as well as descending data. PHP got [SplMinHeap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splminheap.php) and [SplMaxHeap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splmaxheap.php) for this purpose. These built in classes make life easer when dealing with ascending or descending datasets.

A quick example ...

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

use SplMinHeap;

$numbers = [128, 32, 64, 8, 256];
$heap = new SplMinHeap();

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $heap->insert($number);
}

$heap->rewind();
while($heap->valid()) {
    // 8, 32, 64, 128, 256
    echo $heap->current() . PHP_EOL;
    $heap->next();
}
```

The `SplMinHeap` class keeps the minimum automatically on the top. So just use heaps instead of arrays that have no structure. Same goes for `SplMaxHeap` that keeps the highest value on the top.

### Finding the differences

If you want to iterate all data and finding the differences between one to the next, you just have to iterate the heap. It 's ordered anyway.

```
$heap->rewind();
$smallest = $heap->current();
while($heap->valid()) {
    // 8, 32, 64, 128, 256
    $current = $heap->current();
    echo $current . PHP_EOL;
    // 0 (8 - 8), 24 (32 - 8), 32 (64 - 32), 64 (128 - 64), 128 (256 - 128)
    echo "difference to the value before: " . ($current - $smallest) . PHP_EOL;
    $smallest = $current;
    $heap->next();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, the question is about how to check if arrays are in ascending and descending order.  How does this help?

Comment: Actually you 're not missing something. This answer just says that arrays are not the right tool for handling data structures. Arrays are expensive in any way: memory usage is way to high, no structure, re-inventing the wheel for putting structure in arrays. In this case it would be better to refactor the source. Arrays are not made for this. What, if the content of the array is negative and positive? Does an intersection then have to be calculated from the differences of the individual contents, which is then positive or negative, in order to achieve an approximately correct result?

Comment: But if these arrays are being generated elsewhere and passed in and they need to be checked, this doesn't solve the problem.  It's good to give insights into how you could do it, but doesn't always apply to a particular scenario.

Comment: @Marcel, Thank you for your help, I have edited my question and added more details, hopefully it is clear now

Comment: PHP heaps are absolutely useless to solve the OP's problem. A heap sorts data, which will destroy the information we want to extract.

Comment: Yeah @Olivier, we pointed that already out. Nevertheless, thank you for your contribution. That will help us enormously.

Answer (score 0):

I would do simple things like this

```
$data1 = [3,5,7,6,8,9,13,14,17,15,16,16,16,18,22,20,21,20];
$data2 = [23,18,17,17,16,15,16,14,15,10,11,7,4,5];

getTrend($data1) //Returns up
getTrend($data2) // Returns down


function getTrend($arr)
{
  $up = 0;
  $down = 0;
  $prev = "";

   foreach($arr as $val)
  {
    if($prev != "" && $val > $prev)
    {
    $up = $val-$prev;
    }
    else if($prev != "" && $val < $prev)
    {
    $down = $prev-$val ;
    }
    $prev = $val);
   }

if($up > $down)
{
  return "up";
}
else if($down > $up)
{
  return "down";
}
else {
  return "flat";
}

}
```

Comment: This code is equivalent to comparing the first and the last values.

Comment: but up value contains total difference